# Get human readable name for BuiltInParameterGroup enumeration values

Tags: c#, revit, revit-api

Using the Revit API is there a way to get the human readable version of the `BuiltInParameterGroup` enumeration values (Dimensions, Materials and Finishes, etc)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found [this post](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/Autodesk-Revit-API/BuiltinParameterGroup-name/td-p/3065664) on the Autodesk forums that shows how to use the `LabelUtils` class.

```
string humanReadableGroup = 
  LabelUtils.GetLabelFor(BuiltInParameterGroup.PG_MATERIALS);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the code on the of my mind, but you could use the Revit Lookup Snoop (source code comes with it) that comes with the SDK to do this..

Answer (score 0):

You can get the UI/Display name for any `BuiltInParameterGroup` enum value such as the PG_CONSTRAINTS like this:

```
MessageBox.Show(info, LabelUtils.GetLabelFor(BuiltInParameterGroup.PG_CONSTRAINTS) + "Group");
```